# Doubts about a differential negative resistance oscillator

Tags: mosfet, rf, circuit-design, oscillator, differential

let's consider this kind of differential negative resistance oscillator:

[image]

The output of this circuit is VA - VB. My book says the following sentence:

> From a quick analysis of the circuit it can be observed that the function VA is in counterphase with VB. This means that it is possible to make an equivalent half circuit.

I know that the output of a common source stage is in counterphase with the input signal, so from this point of view I understand this sentence. But:

- in this case the gates are not externally excited by a differential signal. So, how can we conclude that VA = - VB?
- since there is not excitation, how can the circuit physically reach that situation? For instance:

1) noise determines a voltage signal on A
2) that signal is amplified by M2 and we see it with 180° phase shift on B
3) the signal on B is amplified by M1 and we see it with 180° phase shift on A

etc

it seems to me that the signals on A and B are in counterphase, but with different amplitudes, since each one is the amplification of the other one, and so the network is not excited in an antisymmetrical way.

Comment: A and B cannot settle down to have different amplitudes because the circuit is symmetrical.

Comment: *A and B are in counterphase, but with different amplitudes* Only during startup will this be the case, at startup (the oscillator has not reached its final and maximum amplitude yet) the amplitudes are increasing A-B-A-B etc... When the oscillator settles at its maximum amplitude, A and B will have the same amplitude as the circuit is symmetrical. There is no reason for A and B not to be equal.

Comment: *since each one is the amplification of the other one* Yes, **during startup** but once settled the amplification (loopgain) becomes **one**. So A = 1 x B and B = 1 x A.

Comment: What is the gain of an amplifier when both input and output are rail-to-rail?

Comment: It is possible to get a wide range of complementary signals so that the capacitor might see a sine wave voltage but depending on the nonlinear RLC Q the current is very nonlinear with all kinds of spurious resonances of pulsed current changes.  http://tinyurl.com/qojzofg  Just slide the supply voltage down or up.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry of the circuit dictates symmetry of the nodes.

Put another way: if the components are equal but the amplitudes aren't, then which node should have the higher amplitude, and why?

If we consider the two halves of the circuit as individual transfer functions H, we have the condition H^2 = 1.  The gain is strictly equal for each stage, so the only steady-state condition is that the gain is the square root, or ±1.  We can exclude the positive result because it's given that each common-source stage is inverting.  If we didn't have reactive elements, this could hold at DC, and indeed the unreactive circuit is bistable.  For the reactive case, the same continuity holds at the bandpass center frequency, and thus it oscillates.

We can also transform the loop gain into a negative resistance between nodes A and B.  We must introduce a probe impedance or source with which to measure that impedance, and then we can find it's something like -1/gm.

Note there is some apparent contradiction here: a negative-resistance amplifier has divergent amplitude when Req < 0, i.e. it never reaches steady state.  This contradicts the assumption that loop gain is 1.  The confusion is because of the different assumptions underlying each claim: negative resistance is true instantaneously in a linearized condition; loop gain assumes AC steady state.

Indeed, strict linearity would contradict the steady-state assumption, because amplitude must converge to zero, diverge to infinity, or remain steady only in the rare condition that complex poles lie on the real-zero axis.  Simply put, an LTI system cannot have nonzero steady-state output.

What will happen in practice, is the LTI assumption is broken: the cycle-averaged gm of each transistor is limited by saturation* at the high end**, and cutoff at the low end.  As amplitude grows, average gm falls, and amplitude stabilizes at the point where the system poles lie on the real axis (that is, if we adjust the LTI equivalent model to follow the system across its nonlinear operating point; which is to say, it's no longer linear, or time-invariant, but suppose we still treated it that way, wink wink).

*Voltage saturation, i.e. entering the triode or Rds(on) region.

**Give or take transfer saturation, i.e. the transistor physically cannot conduct harder, no matter how much more Vgs we apply to it (up to failure), even if we keep the load impedance very small (avoiding voltage saturation) and have unlimited drain current available.  I'm not sure offhand how well this applies to monolithic MOSFET models, but it is definitely a characteristic I've measured in high voltage (power switching) MOSFETs.  If nothing else, a simple mechanism is series source resistance (gm <= 1/Rs), though current saturation (i.e. gm --> 0 for Id ≫ 0) can also occur.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a very good circuit to simulate.  Often oscillators need a 'kick' to get them started, and a step on the power supply usually does it.  Plot the currents vs. time and you'll see the behavior in start-up vs. steady-state is somewhat different.